# Is there a way to make this org-mode option #+OPTIONS: H:5 permanent in init.el?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have this option defined at the top of all my org files `#+OPTIONS: H:5` and I was wondering if there is a way to make it permanent in init.el so I don't have to add it manually to all my org files. It allows my LaTeX exports to have five levels of headings:

```
* First level
* Second
* Third
* Fourth
* Fifth
```

If I don't have the H:5 enabled, the fourth and fifth level headings are indented and they don't look like heading at all. I'm using the "article" document class in LaTeX. So, I'm wondering if there is a way to make  `#+OPTIONS: H:5` permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-Settings) for the variable which is controlled by the `H:5` setting. You will find:

> H
>
> Set the number of headline levels for export (org-export-headline-levels). Below that level, headlines are treated differently. In most back-ends, they become list items.

So you have to fiddle with the variable `org-export-headline-levels`. You can either customize it or set it in your init.el:

```
(setq org-export-headline-levels 5)
```